# List indexing semantic error

Tags: python, list, sum, boolean, range

I'm trying to create a function that takes a list (a) and integer (x) as input and returns true if the list contains 3 elements that sum to the value of x. I'm getting a semantic error when I execute the code that I've written - please advise!

```
def sum_tri(a, x):

    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        for j in range(i, len(a)):
            for k in range(j, len(a)):
                if a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == x:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

>>> a = [1, 5, 8, 2, 6, 55, 90]
>>> x = 103
>>> sum_tri(a, x)
False                # However it should return True
```

Answer (score 4):

You are returning `False` on the first failure, but you should do it only when all the options fail:

```
def sum_tri(a, x):
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        for j in range(i, len(a)):
            for k in range(j, len(a)):
                if a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == x:
                    return True
    return False
a = [1, 5, 8, 2, 6, 55, 90]
x = 103
print sum_tri(a, x)

>>>True
```

---

**Also** you'll need to change the limits of your inner for loops from `len(a)` to `len(a) - 1` or else you'll get:

```
a,x = [1,2,3],8
print sum_tri(a, x)

>>>True
```

because the 2nd and 3rd loops will accept the last element (3 in this case)...

---

The final function should look like:

```
def sum_tri(a, x):
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        for j in range(i, len(a) - 1):
            for k in range(j, len(a) - 1):
                if a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == x:
                    return True
    return False
```

Comment: @ClsForCookies Oh I see! Thank you! :)